# Is there any other way to put some arrays together and be able to call only one element of them randomly?

Tags: javascript

I need to grab the elements of some small arrays and put them together to make a bigger array. But I don't want those small arrays to be the elements of the big array. I just need their elements. Then I need to randomly chose ONLY one element from the big array.
Normally the big array will be:

```
Array.prototype.randomElement = function () {
return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]
}

var small_1_array = [1,2,3,4];
var small_2_array = [5,6,7,8,9];
var small_3_array = [10,11,12];

var big_array = [small_1_array, small_2_array, small_3_array];
console.log("big_array is: " + big_array);
```

Result:

```
big_array is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

The problem with this way is that I can only choose one of the the small arrays(a group of numbers), but not their elements(only a number). For example:

```
console.log("a random number from big_array is: " + big_array.randomElement());
```

Result:

```
a random number from big_array is: 1,2,3,4
```

And this is a solution I could think of:

```
var rearrange_array = (big_array.toString()).split(",");
console.log("rearrange_array is : " + rearrange_array);
```

Result:

```
rearrange_array is : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Now if I execute:

```
console.log("a random number from rearrange_array is: " + rearrange_array.randomElement());
```

the result would be something like this:

```
a random number from rearrange_array is: 2
```

Is there any other way to put some arrays together and be able to call only one element of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply your `randomElement` function twice:

```
console.log("a random number from one of the arrays is: "
  + big_array.randomElement().randomElement());
```

Of course you also could put the small arrays together and choose from the new huge one. The method to do that is [concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var rearrange_array = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], big_array);
// or, without the big_array variable:
var rearrange_array = small_1_array.concat(small_2_array, small_3_array);
// then:
return rearrange_array.randomElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), which

> Returns a new array comprised of this array joined with other array(s) and/or value(s).

In your case:

```
var small_1_array = [1,2,3,4];
var small_2_array = [5,6,7,8,9];
var small_3_array = [10,11,12];

var big_array = small_1_array.concat(small_2_array, small_3_array);
console.log("a random number from big_array is: " + big_array.randomElement());
```